# Where does software go after it is downloaded?

Tags: software-installation

I tried downloading ClamAV and it could not be found. Also I'm clueless on how to install stuff using the terminal. I'm sick of windows and want to learn how this works.

Comment: If you are downloading from a browser then files will be downloaded in ~/Downloads directory. If you installing using Software Center the process will automatically download and install the files for you.

Answer (score 0):

Clamav is a terminal based application, so your best bet is to open a terminal and type `man clamav`. Doing that will tell you if it has been installed, since you won't have the manual page for it if it hasn't. Then you can read the information to learn how to use it.

Note that clamav is only effective against Windows viruses. These by their nature cannot work on Linux and antivirus on Linux is therefore really just to avoid you passing viruses on to Windows users e.g. through Word documents.

Linux is not immune to **malware**, although a well organised and maintained Linux system is extremely well protected compared with Windows.

If you are security conscious, consider installing chkrootkit and rkhunter, as well as a script blocker in your browser to block javascript when you surf the web e.g. No-Script. If you have open ports (e.g. if you use SSH), you would also do well to set-up a firewall e.g. gufw.

Comment: Thank you for such a concise answer.   I may be asking more since I'm such a noobie